# Apache ssl redirect using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to do this: if they do `https://example.com` I want to redirect them to `https://www.example.com` (add the `www.`). I have tried oodles of things to no avail.

```
Redirect https://example.com/<anything> to https://www.example.com/<anything>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code is in httpd.conf but has been tried in .htaccess and ssl.conf.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned on Rewriting via `RewriteEngine On` or is mod_rewrite installed? Otherwise, your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Redirect` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) does only work on the URL path. But it’s possible with mod_rewrite. This rule will work in any configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And don’t forget the obligatory `RewriteEngine on` like (Residuum already said)(1278432#1278432).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Of course, don't forget to replace "www.example.com" with your own domain.

Comment: If you look closely at the OP port 80 is not used at all.