# Apache redirect .net, .org, .co to .com using Rewrite or serveralias

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a website. I bought all (mydomain.com|net|org|co) domains for my website. Now, I want to redirect all my requests to mydomain.com.Presently, in my httpd.conf, I have ReWrite rules for forwarding http requests to https.

`For forwarding all http requests to https

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

I combined my existing settings with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1278262/1300040) and I tried following code:


`RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.org$ 

RewriteRule ^ http://example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

It is working fine for http requests but not for https(https://mydomain.net/info). I got SSL certificate for `mydomain.com`. It is displaying me This Connection is Untrusted page.

What would be best way to handle this scenario. Can anyone guide me on this

Thanks in advance,
deadMan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried above code. I have SSL certificate mydomain.com. When I used your rule, https://mydomain.net throwing me Untrusted connection instead of redirect.